# storyboard - Image size too big when running app

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have two png files:
logo.png (97x47 px) and logo@2.png (197x95 px)
All I have in the storyboard is a view and an imageView on it, with the logo image.
When I'm setting the image to logo, and add constrains to be in the center, 
when I'm running the app - the image is very large.
I've tried to set it to Aspect Fit but it wasn't the problem.

I'm running it on iPhone 6 (so I guess it's using the logo@2.png)

What could cause this?

Comment: Small remark: If logo.png has 97x47 resolution, the 2x will be 194x94 and 3x should be 291x 141. The other solution is just to create a vector image in .pdf format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set 4 contraints :

1. Fixed width
2. Fixed height
3. Align center X
4. Align center Y

After this, you should name your big image "logo@2x.png", you forgot the "x".

Example (UIActivityIndicator 37x37 centered on view) :

[image]